# is $f(x) = 20x^5-35x^4+10x^3-1$ irreducible over $\Bbb Q [\sqrt{3}]$?

Tags: solution-verification, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, galois-extensions

I was studying for a Galois theory exam when I saw this question and was stumped.
It is not hard to check that $f$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ (since $x^5\cdot f(\frac{1}{x})$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$  [Eisenstein criterion $p=5$]).

Here is my main problem, most questions like this have a polynomial for which we can compute the roots exactly. But, in our case, $Gal(L/{\Bbb Q}) \cong S_5$ ($L\subseteq \Bbb C$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $\Bbb Q$) so we can't even express the roots in a useful way.

I tried taking a similar approach by trying to show $x^5\cdot f(\frac{1}{x})$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{3}]$, again by applying the Eisenstein criterion but now over $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{3}]$. However this would require knowing how $20,35,10$ factor in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{3}]$ which is probably not the way to go.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I think this is a solution but I am not sure:

If $f$ splits over $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{3}]$ then one both of it's factors are of degree less or equal to 4, hence they are solvable by radicals but since their coefficients are in $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{3}]$ then the roots are expressable as radicals and so $f$ is solvable in radicals which is a contradiction to $Gal(L/{\Bbb Q}) \cong S_5$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 3]$ is not a UFD, so could you even apply Eisenstein? (That is: As opposed to just it being tedious, is it even possible?)

Comment: Since given polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q} $ we have $[\mathbb {Q} (a):\mathbb{Q}] =5$ where $a$ is any root of the polynomial. Next you can note that $\sqrt{3}\notin \mathbb {Q} (a) $ (why?) so that $[\mathbb{Q} (a, \sqrt{3}):\mathbb {Q} ]=10$. Deduce that $a$ is of degree $5$ over $\mathbb {Q} (\sqrt {3})$.

Comment: You don't really need Galois theory here although your solution is correct. The problem is that the technique will fail for a polynomial like $x^5-2$ which is solvable by radicals and yet is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: Also I don't really know if the polynomial in question has Galois group $S_5$.

Comment: It has 3 real roots and a pair of conjugate roots, hence its Galois group has a two cycle (corresponding to complex conjugation). Also 5 must divide the order of the Galois group and so it has a 5 cycle. $S_5$ is generated by a two cycle and a five cycle so the Galois group is $S_5$.

Comment: @yotammaoz: [This graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/02pj5nrltu) suggests that there's only one root. (Of course, this is not a formal proof...)

Comment: Right, sorry I should have mentioned I was talking about $x^5 \cdot f(\frac{1}{x})$. Showing this is irreducible is equivalent to showing f is.

Comment: @yotammaoz: The same is true for that polynomial as well. (The roots of $g(x) = x^5 f(\frac1x)$ and $f(x)$ are reciprocals of each other.)